# c++, денежные системы

Tags: c++

**есть задачка:**
*Старая английская денежная система использует три единицы для хранения денежных величин: фунты, шиллинги и пенсы. Один фунт (pound) состоит из 20 шиллингов, 1 шиллинг (shilling) – из 12 пенсов (penny, pence). Самая маленькая монета («фартинг») равняется четверти пенса, поэтому все расчеты требуется вести с точностью до ¼ пенса. Требуется создать класс для хранения информации о наличии денег в этой денежной системе. Сумма денег может быть как положительной, так и отрицательной. Максимальная (по модулю) хранимая величина – 1 млрд. фунтов....*

### Как лучше хранить деньги? В голову приходят такие решения:

1. хранить все в фартингах long long (64 бита), а потом переводить, когда нужно вывести
2. int фунты, char/short шилинги, float пенсы
3. int фунты, char/short шилинги, char/short пенсы и char/short фартинги
4. int фунты, шилинги пенсы и фартинги хранить в фартингах short

В первом случае будет проще всего проводить арифметические операции, но многова-то памяти, по сравнению с третьим вариантом. В третьем варианте затратно будет производить арифм. операции. четвертый вариант экономнее на 25% первого, но операции по прежнему не очень удобно проводить.

---

Как бы вы это реализовали?
Спасибо

Comment: Я бы хранил в фартингах - ваш первый вариант. 8 байт. В третьем варианте вы получаете геморрой и больший размер. А если сумма будет вам дана как 2 миллиона фартингов - что вы станете делать?...

Comment: @Harry. Ну да, если даже хранить в 3-ем в char-ах, то в сумме получится 56 бит, а вот 4-ый вариант - 48 и считать проще. Я реализовывал как раз в фартингах, не желая получить геморрой

Comment: Это просто единственное *естественное* решение.

Comment: На счет второго варината - "Если бы мне давали доллар каждый раз, когда кто-то использует `float` для деенжных переменных, у меня было бы 99999,9999998 долларов" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 вариант не рассматриваем. 3 и 4 варианты все равно будут занимать по 8 байт как и 1, из-за выравнивания. Можно выравнивание отключить и получить небольшой выигрыш по памяти, но тогда вы получите снижение производительности при работе с такими структурами.

Поэтому на самом деле рабочий вариант только один - первый.